# Cocoa: Subclassing NSProgressIndicator on Lion

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mobile, nsprogressindicator

I have a problem that is driving me crazy. I want to subclass `NSProgressIndicator` in its "Bar" form to change the color of the progress bar based on a couple of logic states. For that i basically override the `-drawRect:` as usual. However a very strange thing happens on Lion. Even if my `-drawRect` just calls the superclass' implementation via `[super drawRect:]` and does nothing else at all the whole progress bar will be displayed using the style that was used *before* Lion. If you remember, with Lion the progress bar style has changes to a more flat and sleek look from the prior glassy one.

Again, just overriding `-drawRect` to do nothing but to call the superclass' implementation changes the style of the progress bar to Leopard's. Does anyone have a slightest idea of what is going on and how i can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

How about making the progress indicator layer-backed and applying a Core Image filter to recolour it?

Comment: I also tried around with that but can't get the bar to drawn in a different color. Rather more, the filter is applied to everything and no bar is visible at all. Here's what I tried. http://pastebin.com/AYQHY4st

Comment: @guitarflow why oh why did you ever remove the paste?!

Answer (score 1):

CustomeProgressIndicator.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface CustomProgressIndicator : NSView {

    double m_minValue;
    double m_maxValue;
    double m_value;
}

- (void)setMaxValue:(double)newMaxValue;
- (void)setMinValue:(double)newMinValue;
- (void)setDoubleValue:(double)newDoubleValue;
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect;   
@end
```

CustomProgressIndicator.m:

```
#import "CustomProgressIndicator.h"

@implementation CustomProgressIndicator

- (void)setMaxValue:(double)newMaxValue
{
    m_maxValue = newMaxValue;
}

- (void)setMinValue:(double)newMinValue
{
    m_minValue = newMinValue;
}

- (void)setDoubleValue:(double)newDoubleValue
{
    m_value = newDoubleValue;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [[NSColor grayColor] set];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:dirtyRect];

    double width = ((m_value - m_minValue) / (m_maxValue - m_minValue));
    CGRect bar = dirtyRect;
    bar.size.width *= width;

    [[NSColor darkGrayColor] set];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:bar];    
}
```