# An NSProgressIndicator with a different colour in the drawn bar

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsprogressindicator

I'd like to change the color of the default gradient that is drawn inside the `NSProgressIndicator` bar. What's the easiest approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I display the spinning NSProgressIndicator in a different color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456445/how-can-i-display-the-spinning-nsprogressindicator-in-a-different-color) Check the answer by Kelan.

Comment: @NayanChauhan: Nope its not a duplicate. And Kelan's answer is not for bar based, its for circular indicator. Check my answer...could be the easiest one...

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to change the HUE....refer the screen shot for better understanding...

[image]

Then you will have the Progress bar :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10643148/244340), you could apply a Core Image filter to recolour it. That'd be the easiest way, as you wouldn't have to animate it yourself.

If you wanted a completely different look, then override `drawRect:` and draw whatever you want, using `[self doubleValue]` and `[self maxValue]` to find out where to draw. That won't get you any animation or gradients for free though.

Comment: And how to apply the filter on a NSProgressIndicator? How to get the image to apply on it?

Answer (score 0):

try [this](https://github.com/kelan/yrk-spinning-progress-indicator) code. extract `YRKSpinningProgressIndicator` class and use it as as-usual progress indicator

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to change de Hue as others said, but I was getting a lot of issues to get the right specific color i wanted. Maybe I just don't understand the color system too much...

But what did worked for me, and seems to be the most direct way to get a specific color, was using the CIColorMonochrome filter, where You can set any RGB color you want:

[image]

and programmatically:

```swift
let myCustomColor: CIColor(red: 10, green: 10, blue: 10)
if let colorMonochrome = CIFilter(name: "CIColorMonochrome", parameters: [kCIInputColorKey: myCustomColor]) {
    progressIndicator.contentFilters.append(colorMonochrome)
}
```